# Getting "'file' is different from the same file on the system" when I attempt to update through synaptic

Tags: apt

Encountered an error while updating through Synaptic Manager. Subsequent updates gave the error at the bottom of the output. I'm a noob so any help is appreciated.

```
al@al:~$ sudo apt-get -f upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic skype
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/202 kB of archives.
After this operation, 493 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 310056 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (from .../libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Specific answer**

Try these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -r libjack-jackd2-0
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The commands remove the offending file, attempts to fix the broken dependency and updates your system.

---

**General answer**

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/**libjack-jackd2-0**_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

If you are getting an `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` (**Should be error code (1)**), you can attempt to fix this with the following things in mind:

- Take note of the package name after `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. In this case, the filename is `libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb`, so the package name is `libjack-jackd2-0` (take the filename up until the first '_', generally). With these in mind, just run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -r libjack-jackd2-0
  sudo apt-get -f install
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

Comment: Dpkg returns most of errors as code (1) if it failed. That's not the important message, the important one is `'./usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I know this question is already answered and the answer is maked as accepted.

However I know another solution.

```
rm /usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz
```

This would solve conflict and `dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file.deb` would be run successfully.