# DPKG upgrade error

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171205/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

When I'm upgrading with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

My terminal shows this:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/resolvconf_1.63ubuntu16_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some problem with package: resolvconf_1.63ubuntu16_all.deb, try:

> sudo apt-get install -f