# How can I fix dependency problems with firefox?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I can't do anything from `Ubuntu Software Center` or from `Terminal`

This is what i get from command line:

```
deus@comp:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for deus: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
firefox-globalmenu : Depends: firefox (= 18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
deus@comp:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
firefox
Suggested packages:
latex-xft-fonts firefox-gnome-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 203826 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking firefox (from .../firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/plugins', which is also in package adobe-flashplugin 11.2.202.261-0precise1
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
deus@comp:~$ sudo apt-get clean
deus@comp:~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
firefox-globalmenu : Depends: firefox (= 18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
deus@comp:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
firefox
Suggested packages:
latex-xft-fonts firefox-gnome-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 23.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main firefox i386 18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 [23.7 MB]
Fetched 23.7 MB in 1min 27s (271 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 203826 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking firefox (from .../firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/plugins', which is also in package adobe-flashplugin 11.2.202.261-0precise1
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas of what's going wrong?

**EDIT/ANSWER TO COMMENTS**

@Lucio I did what you said and here is the result.

```
deus@comp:~$ sudo dpkg -r firefox
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching firefox
deus@comp:~$ ^C
deus@comp:~$ apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
deus@comp:~$ sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
firefox
Suggested packages:
latex-xft-fonts firefox-gnome-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 203826 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking firefox (from .../firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/plugins', which is also in package adobe-flashplugin 11.2.202.261-0precise1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @Aditya The resolution of this problem isn't there because the root of the issue is not based on *unmet dependencies*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see you have problems installing `firefox` because it is trying to overwrite a directory that is used by `adobe-flashplugin`. So you need to uninstall this plugin first:

```
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin*
```

Now install you will be able to install firefox without problems.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

---

For further information related with the problem `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` review [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/185123/62483).

Comment: that didn't do it

Comment: Yes, I did. I also messed with a lot of stuff. I think I removed everything relevant to it. But still I can't install it again. I get an error when trying to re-install.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help... I bet the comments above don't show much gratitude. Sorry if that's how it seemed.

Comment: Remove `adobe-flashplugin` and try again. To remove: `sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin*`

Comment: As simple as that... It worked! Add that to your answer if you want. I'll mark it as accepted anyway.