# How to resolve dpkg error code 1?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

I'm having issues with installing these two updates:

- linux-generic-pae
- linux-image-generic-pae

Getting the following errors every time I try to upgrade:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae (3.2.0-35.55) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic-pae)
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.35.40); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/185123/25656

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/171205/25656 and other `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` type questions.

Comment: Not the same as my problem, unfortunately

Comment: @vasa1 `dpkg` can have an exit status of `1` for a wide variety of problems; as the OP says, this is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae` 
then `sudo apt-get install linux-image` or `sudo apt-get -f install` I expect would clean up for you also after that first command.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036016