# I am trying to remove OpenOffice to go back to LibreOffice, but I keep getting an error message

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I am trying to remove OpenOffice and go back to LibreOffice but I keep getting this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And then when try running `apt-get -f install` I get this:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.0.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: How do you try to uninstall it? Also, we need the complete error in `apt-get -f install` not just the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in a terminal :

```
sudo dpkg -r libreoffice-common
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**SOURCE**:[Getting "'file' is different from the same file on the system" when I attempt to update through synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171205/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command...

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-common
```

if similar error comes but with different package then try to install that package first and then try libreoffice-common