# when i try to install any thing in ubuntu 12.04 i get this error

Tags: 12.04, installation, dependencies

`sudo apt-get install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libjson0 : Breaks: libjson0:i386 (!= 0.10-1.2ubuntu2) but 0.9-1ubuntu1 is installed libjson0:i386 : Breaks: libjson0 (!= 0.9-1ubuntu1) but 0.10-1.2ubuntu2 is installed
teamviewer : Depends: lib32asound2 but it is not installed
          Depends: lib32z1 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Can any one help me over this

Comment: did you try to run `sudo apt-get -f install` as it says?

Comment: yes i done that but i get error as dpkg: error processing libjson0:i386 (--configure):
 libjson0:i386 0.9-1ubuntu1 cannot be configured because libjson0:amd64 is in a different version (0.10-1.2ubuntu2)
dpkg: error processing libjson0 (--configure):
 libjson0:amd64 0.10-1.2ubuntu2 cannot be configured because libjson0:i386 is in a different version (0.9-1ubuntu1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libjson0:i386
 libjson0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/171205/file-is-different-from-the-same-file-on-the-system

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the particular `libjson0`,`libjson0:i386` packages forcely without removing it's dependencies,

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libjson0 libjson0:i386
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

sir...
you shuld enter this commands

```
apt-get -f install
```

if this don't work try this out

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get remove libjson0:i386
sudo apt-get install libjson0
sudo apt-get install lib32asound2
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

if the command `sudo apt-get remove libjson0:i386` didn't work go to next or
install it with synapatic package manger

> *search it in dash 
>   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSuMb.png)