# Processing error while installing "ubuntu-restricted-extras" package

Tags: apt, software-installation

I just installed new Ubuntu 14.04. I read a post on the internet "20 things to do after installing Ubuntu 14.04", so I executed the command as they said.

```
# Install multimedia codecs
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

But after this several process were going and suddenly I got this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171205/getting-file-is-different-from-the-same-file-on-the-system-when-i-attempt-to

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be a broken package what can have caused this error.

To install ttf-mscorefonts-installer you can do this.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

You will be provided with a prompt to accept the EULA (End User License Agreement) after which installation will proceed further.

When you see a violet background with grey type Eula window up, push key TAB key on your keyboard and accept ok. TAB again to accept Yes. So the installation will install Microsoft true-type fonts to your Ubuntu or Mint system.

After the installation is complete, you can check the installed fonts using applications like LibreOffice Writer or Abiword.

You don't need to install everything recommended by every website; you still have to use a little common sense on what apps or tools you wanna keep on your fresh installation and what new changes do you wanna add in etc.

[This article](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/thingstweaks-to-do-after-install-of.html) is good since it explains a little.